# How to encapsulate properly some display logic used inside a *ngFor primitives?

Tags: angular, angular5, ngfor

I'm new to angular 5 and still trying to start with some good practices. I already read on this subject but I can't find something which help me to make a choice.

Let's say that we have this basic list of items to display. The **href** attribute depends on some logic.

I wrote a function **isOK()** in the associated component which takes the item from the list as a parameter and return a boolean depending of some properties of this item.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of itemList">
        <a [href]="isOK(item) ? aPath + item.name: '#'"  class="btn btn-default download-button"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Does it exist a better way to do that ? does a pipe will be a better approach in such a situation ?

Comment: your are correct, a pipe will be better, if you put a console.log inside the isOk function, this function will be called every time you move the mouse (because the change detection strategy), also you can use a if condition to diplay the link instead assigning a #

Comment: That's fine. What I would wonder is: what's the point of a link pointing to the current page? Is it wise to use the same path for all the items?

Comment: For testability I would recommend using the isOK() method with a return type string and doing the logic inside the Typescript part of the component

Comment: @Ricardo no, isOK won't be called every time you move the mouse. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apgv6f?file=app%2Fapp.component.html if you don't believe me.

Comment: @JBNizet  In my case, it's a link used to download something, if there is nothing to download I will disabled the link or hide it.

Comment: @Ricardo What I am not sure about a Pipe is the fact that, in my case it will be something I will use only for this component. If I understand well a pipe will be shared by different components, maybe I'm misunderstanding the purpose of a pipe ?

Comment: @Yoann no, you're not misunderstanding. And a pipe won't help you achieve what you **really** want to achieve, i.e. using *ngIf (to hide the link), or ngClass (to style it differently), or (click) (to test if the link should do something or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a method in the component like

```
getButtonLink(item: Type) {
    if(this.isOK(item)) {
        return `${aPath}/${item.name}`
    }

    return '#'
}
```

Improves readability a lot and also makes it easier to test.

And use it like

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of itemList">
        <a [href]="getButtonLink(item)"  class="btn btn-default download-button"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```